# open comma seperated text and read the file with specific field data item with specific id and it can be use in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv

[This is a CSV file contains column name.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoCq1.png)

[This second image is a comma separated requirement file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0V2ML.png)

In this req. file first line contain Excel Name,Path of the excel fiel,dbname
Second line contain sr.no,Column Name,columndtype,userrequireddtype and so on.
What I want, I want read file with the help of "with open command" and read every element and put into the dataframe.
Suppose :
df=pd.read_excel("path of the excel file") this path read from req. file.
df[column name] and I want read column from the req. file.
suppose first column name dtype is int and convert into the another dtype i.e 'object'.
df['column name'].astype('object') this 'object' read by the req. file.

Comment: "bold" and "italics" are not features available in CSV files. Did you manually insert the `*` to try to format the sample data you provided? Or are the `*` values actually in the CSV content?

Comment: bold and italics word used for understanding for us. ** star represent the bold and single *  represent the italic and both format specifying the columns name and path of the comma seperated file.

Comment: For future reference, instead of coming up with your own way of identifying different aspects of the CSV you can use "second entry of the first row" and "second column excluding the header row."

Answer (score 0):

The scope of your question is not clear, but if the CSV file name is `sample.csv` you can read the data using

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv('sample.csv')
```

You can then determine the column names using

```
list(df.columns)
```

And you can access a given column using

```
df['postgres']
```

Comment: There is a distinction between "the file has a .csv extension" and "the file content is consistent with CSV conventions." Given the example data you provided, it looks like the content is consistent with CSV conventions even though the file extension is not .csv.

Comment: If your data does not include headers as the first row, you can specify what the columns should be named. In that case, please update your question to reflect the initial data you are starting with.